# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error when triying to connect Power-Bi models in Alm-Toolkit

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to upload the changes i have done in a dataset in local to my Dev workspace in Power bi services. When the selection where changes "validate selection"  are validated before the update it brings me the error. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Anyone knows how to fix it? I have tried with and without VPN connection and still doesn´t work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN1y8.png)

Comment: Update: It is happening because of the KPI´S, anyone knows if it´s possible to migrate also the KPI´s without that problem

Comment: I've got the same error message. I migrated back to the December release of Power BI - this has not fixed the issue. Nothing loads (for the compare) for me.

Comment: The problem was resolved updating to the latest version of Power Bi and ALM Toolkit. Now is working perfectly for me.